# Biblatex: cite an article published in several installments (multiple years and volumes)

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLaTeX with the `verbose-ibid` style and have customized it in accord with the specifications for my thesis. I now come to an article that was published in several installments over a period of 2 years, but always in the same journal and with the same title. I want to know how I can represent this to BibLaTeX and get an appropriate bibliography entry and citations.

Let us say that the installments are:

- vol. 43 (1937), pp. 1-23
- vol. 43 (1937), pp. 390-417
- vol. 44 (1937), pp. 244-280
- vol. 45 (1938), pp. 17-43
- vol. 45 (1938), pp. 117-130

Note that this journal published two volumes per year.

The bibliography entry may be the most complex part. It should look something like this:

> J. Doe, *Insights on the history of plumbing,* in *Plumbatica* 43 (1937), pp. 1-23, pp. 390-417, 44 (1937), pp. 244-280, 45 (1938), pp. 17-43, pp. 117-130.

I am flexible about the details of this: it would be acceptable to repeat the volume and year thus:

> J. Doe, *Insights on the history of plumbing,* in *Plumbatica* 43 (1937), pp. 1-23, 43 (1937), pp. 390-417, 44 (1937), pp. 244-280, 45 (1938), pp. 17-43, 45 (1938), pp. 117-130.

Because there is only such item in the bibliography, I would be perfectly happy with a manual solution that involved sticking everything after the first page range (1-23) into a special field that would be glommed on to the end of the bibliography entry. Perhaps I could just stick `\ppno~1--23, \ppno~390--417, 44 (1937), \ppno~244--280, 45 (1938), \ppno~17--43, \ppno~117--130` in the `Pages` field.

The other problem is the citations. When I first introduce this source, I will list it with other sources on the same subject, and so I will have something very much like the bibliography entry, since this is a verbose style. Then I will proceed to cite passages from it. Each citation must have the correct volume and year.

The thought occurred to me of using 5 entries in the bib file, one for each installment. However, I don't want 5 different entries in the bibliography, and with the verbose-ibid style, citations after the first would be shortened as if each installment were an independent source.

**Edit:** here is the requested MWE. The results are acceptable, although they are occasionally a bit too verbose (see below). My question was really about best practices. If the best practice in this case is to abuse the pages field, I suppose it's answered.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
    title = {Insights on the history of plumbing},
    author = {Doe, J.},
    journal = {Plumbatica},
    volume = {43},
    pages = {\ppno~1--23, \ppno~390--417, 44 (1937), \ppno~244--280, 45 (1938), \ppno~17--43, \ppno~117--130},
    year = {1937}}
@article{ref2,
    title = {The rise and fall of asbestos piping},
    author = {Newman, D.},
    journal = {Annals of Plumbing},
    volume = {35},
    pages = {289--299},
    year = {1965}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\lipsum[4]\footcites{ref1}{ref2}

\lipsum[1]\footcite[44 (1937), \ppno~250-256]{ref1}
\lipsum[5]\footcite[44 (1937), \pno~254]{ref1}

\lipsum[9]\footcite[297]{ref2}
\lipsum[2]\footcite[43 (1937) \ppno~15-18]{ref1}

\lipsum[6]\footcite[43 (1937) \ppno~15-18]{ref1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: formatted example 1]

In these citations, which appear on the first page, footnote 3 would ideally not repeat the volume and year, but would just have "Ibid., p. 254." However, I recognize that the ideal may not be worth the effort it would take to achieve.

[image: formatted example 2]

This is from page 2. In this case, I don't understand why footnote 5 does not just read "Ibid.", because the location passed to footcite is identical.

Comment: Can you give us a MWE and explain why it doesn't work to abuse one specific field for the information (what I would do here)?

Comment: I suppose your question about footnote 5 above is really about footnote 6. If one enables the `ibidpage=true` option `\footcite[244]{ref1}` after a `\footcite[244]{ref1}` does indeed only yield an "ibid." without any page number. This behaviour is only enabled if the optional postnote is detected to be a page number; since `43 (1937) \ppno~15-18` decidedly is not a page number, this feature is not available here. (See also musicman's comment in his answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution for your problem is, to differ between bibliography entry and citation entries:

In My MWE `doe_all` will only be printed in the bibliography, but not used for cites (you can of course, if you want to...), and `doe_43` etc. are only used in the cites, but are excluded from the bibliography by their keyword `hideinbib`.

`doe_43` etc. will copy their informations from `doe_all` via `crossref` and only overwrite the individual data, so you have to type author+title only in `doe_all`.

As you can see, the `ibid` works now, too. I think it's normal for `verbose_ibid` to print `ibid.` + the pages again, if you refer to the same page. To modify this you have to set the option `ibidpage=true`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe_all,
    title = {Insights on the history of plumbing},
    author = {Doe, J.},
    journal = {Plumbatica},
    % pages = {43 (1937), \ppno~1--23, \ppno~390--417, 44 (1937), \ppno~244--280, 45 (1938), \ppno~17--43, \ppno~117--130},
    year = {1937},
    volume = {43},
    pages = {\ppno~1--23, \ppno~390--417, 44 (1937), \ppno~244--280, 45 (1938), \ppno~17--43, \ppno~117--130}
}
@article{doe_43a,
    crossref={doe_all},
    volume={43},
    year={1937},
    pages={1-23},
    keywords={hideinbib}
}
@article{doe_43b,
    crossref={doe_all},
    volume={43},
    year={1937},
    pages={390-417},
    keywords={hideinbib}
}
@article{doe_44,
    crossref={doe_all},
    volume={44},
    year={1937},
    pages={244-280},
    keywords={hideinbib}
}
@article{doe_45a,
    crossref={doe_all},
    volume={45},
    year={1938},
    pages={17-43},
    keywords={hideinbib}
}
@article{doe_45b,
    crossref={doe_all},
    volume={45},
    year={1938},
    pages={117-130},
    keywords={hideinbib}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

43a\autocite[22]{doe_43a}, again\autocite[23]{doe_43a}\par
43b\autocite[400]{doe_43b}, again\autocite[401]{doe_43b}\par
44\autocite[250]{doe_44}, again\autocite[251]{doe_44}\par
45a\autocite[30]{doe_45a}, again\autocite[31]{doe_45a}\par
45b\autocite[120]{doe_45b}, same page\autocite[120]{doe_45b}\par

\printbibliography[notkeyword=hideinbib]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of making up a new `keyword`, we could just use `options = {skipbib=true},` (and `skiplos`, or even `dataonly`) See §3.1.3.2 *Type/Entry Options*, p. 62 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). You might also want to mention that `doe_all` appears in the bibliography thanks to `mincrossref=2` (the default definition).

Comment: nice additions, thx. I should read the manual, someday...

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution, but I prefer my own MWE. Your solution treats every installment as if it were an independent source, so that the first citation of each installment gives complete bibliographic information. I see the installments as conceptually composing a single source, like a multi-volume book.